# Django can't figurout how to pass paramater from url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to pass parameter from url. I have tried many tutorials and can't figure out what am i doing wrong.
my url from url.py:

```
url(r'^reports/(?P<test>\d+)/$', views.reports,name='reports'), # report view
```

my view from view.py:

```
def reports(request, test=0 ):
    title = "Reports" # title shown in browser window
    view ="admin/pc/reports.html"# where is the page view
    user_name = request.user.get_username() #User name
    return render(request, 'admin/home.html', {"title":title,"USER_NAME" : user_name,"page" : view, 'pid':test})
```

and my template:

```
{% block content %}
REPORTSz id = {{pid }}
{% endblock %}
```

but no matter what I do I always get:

> Reverse for 'reports' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}'
>   not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/reports/(?P\d+)/$']

So my question is how to correctly pass parameter from url?

Comment: What line produces this error? It looks like you are using `reverse()` function and not passing required argument (`test`)

Comment: it says : In template ...\templates\admin\home.html, error at line 0 
my navigation link looks like this: 
    <li><a href="{% url "reports"%}">Reports</a></li>
 and as i understand it should go to reports with test=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag in Django templates, you need to pass your `test` parameter:

```
href="{% url "reports" test="some_value" %}"
```

because `test` parameter is required in your URL.

Comment: Thank you, this was giving me a  headache for a week now